# Play continious video Streaming without any break in android

Tags: android

I need to play continious videos one after the other in android application. I have 5 parts in an movie and i need to continiously play all the parts without any break. My issues is when i prepare next video (part2) it struck's in between and after a pause it plays the video. I need someone to help me how can i avoid the black frame that appears before starting next video. Data is coming from server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may i know the video file format?

Comment: create 2 instance of Mediaplayer and let one load while other is playing and then switch display. It requires some patience and hardwork but its possible. There is no other known way of doing it !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [code](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/) you can refer and try :

**[Android Tutorial 3: Custom Progressive Audio Streaming with MediaPlayer](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)**